# executing python script with args pars via ansible

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I'm trying to execute a python script with args parser via ansible 
i want to put all my argument in a single `extra_var` but i im missing something

lets say my python script can get a username `-u` and a password `-p`
and my ansible script has a single var `my_args`

```
script: /tmp/args.py "{{ my_args }}"
```

when i run my playbook like this :

```
ansible-playbook my_ansible_playbook.yml -e "my_args='-u my_username -p my_password'"
```

the result im getting is:

username =  `my_username -p my_password`

password = `default_password`

what am i missing?

how do i send each value to the correct value with a single extra_var?

Comment: Try this way and see if it changes something: `script: "/tmp/args.py {{ my_args }}"`

Comment: thanks @Zeitounator, i tried so many options and i cant believe i missed this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont quote the entire script value, yaml sees the it as a string containing double quotes with a value inside (later interpreted by jinja2). In the end you script is called with a single parameter being your full templated string.

To pass all params as you are trying, you need to quote the entire string.

See the following example as an illustration:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Show the extra var itself
      debug:
        var: myvar

    - name: Quotes in command (wrong)
      debug:
        msg: myscript.py "{{ myvar }}"

    - name: No quotes (good) - simple command with params
      debug:
        msg: "myscript.py {{ myvar }}"
```

And the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook tmp.yml -e "myvar='-u toto -p bingo'"

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show the extra var itself] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "myvar": "-u toto -p bingo"
}

TASK [Quotes in command (wrong)] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "myscript.py \"-u toto -p bingo\""
}

TASK [No quotes (good) - simple command with params] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "myscript.py -u toto -p bingo"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```